# Jquery Select Dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Several similar question exist, but after fighting with this for a day or so I feel the need to ask because the vast majority of the answers refer to adding event handlers to elements.

I am not interested in adding an event handler to the elements in question, rather I am interested in adding additional dynamic content to dynamically generated content.

The app works thusly:
load a modal form dynamically upon the click of a static element (working properly)

```
function loadModal(target,modalId) {
    console.log("==================> loadModal() Entry");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost/retrieve-modal/'+modalId,
        success : function (text) {
            $("#"+modalId)[0].innerHTML = text;
            modalSaveIntercept($("#"+modalId)[0])
        },
        failure : function (e) {
            console.log("something is wrong");
        }
    })
}
```

Then I have a save interceptor that overrides the default save behavior of my form here this is also working properly, (I suspect because I am loading this event handler at the time of loading the modal)

```
function modalSaveIntercept(eventTarget) {
    if(eventTarget.hasChildNodes()) {
        eventTarget.childNodes.forEach(function(e) {
            if(e.tagName == "FORM") {
                console.log("found the form: " + e.id + " applying save override listener");
                $("#"+e.id).submit(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(e);
                });
                modalSaveIntercept(e)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the above attaches a listener to the form loaded into my modal and rather than firing the default behavior of a Save button click, it fires my submitForm() function which is here:

```
function submitForm(form) {

    let payload = constructPayloadFromFormData(form);

    validate(payload).then(function(v) {
        console.log("response Data:");
        for(let p in v) {
            if(v.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                constructInvalidFeedbackForProperty(p,v[p])
            }
        }
    });
}
```

this function constructs a payload from the form data (working fine) then executes another ajax call inside of validate() - I wait for the return call from ajax and then iterate through an array of validation data to confirm the form's validity. However, here is where the problem is:

```
function constructInvalidFeedbackForProperty(prop,e) {
    let el = $("#" + "ic-role-" + prop);
    console.log(el);
    el.append("<div class=\"invalid-feedback\">problem</div>");
}
```

the problem is the append - I cannot seem to fire that method. I can select the element as the console.log(el) writes to the log the correctly identified element in my dom.

What am I doing wrong?

I have created a contrived jsfiddle for a sample of the problem. I actually believe it may be that an input field is not something you can append to... perhaps? https://jsfiddle.net/jtango/xpvt214o/987051/

Comment: You create `el` and add content to it, but where do you add it to the DOM?

Comment: The loadModal call adds several form elements to the Dom El in the context of construct invalid feedback function represents a single hopefully selectable element from the set that gets added

Comment: Try `submitForm(event.target);` also check if the validate promise is passing the right data to the resolved callback.

Comment: I definitely get the right data back from the callback and it's available in the construct invalid feedback context since I can print out to the log. SubmitForm(event.target) will give me the form element right? How would I use that element? I'm after the specific input field that has a problem as identified by my array of validation errors

Comment: According to the docs, append should perform the Dom manipulation: http://api.jquery.com/append/. What happens if you console log el after you’ve called append()? Can you provide a jsfiddle for the example?

Comment: If `el` is e.g. `input` you cannot `append` to it because it cannot have `content`.

Comment: There we go - I updated the fiddle - I should have been using 'after' since you cannot append to an input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I messed around with your fiddle a bit. If you inspect the input element that is created you can see that your append does work. It's just not displaying. If you are trying to edit what is in the input box then you must use `val()`

Here is a copy of your fiddle that will display inside the input:

```
$("#top").on("click", function(){
  $("#form").append("<label>some label: </label><input type=\"text\" id=\"myinput\">");
});

$("#btm").on("click",function(){
    $("#myinput").val("<div>I will not appear</div>");
});
```

Comment: I did see that - which is why I mentioned at the end of my question perhaps I cannot 'append' to an input tag. I suppose I didn't realize append was creating a child within the tag and not a sibling. What I am after is an adjacent (sibling) to the input tag. ie: <input></input><my new tag></my new tag>

Comment: You can append to the parentElement to do this. And I believe there is a method to append after a specific child element to control where it goes. I can edit my answer if you need a further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As your shared https://jsfiddle.net/jtango/xpvt214o/987051/ It will not appear, this is wrong way to append any HTML element inside "input box" or any of form elements. it should allow to set only new attribute or value.

check screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FBgn.png

So verify your below code if it's similar then it will not work:

```
let el = $("#" + "ic-role-" + prop);
console.log(el);
el.append("<div class=\"invalid-feedback\">problem</div>");
```